# User Out Of Office or Vacation - "Delegate" User or "Substitute" User

Tags: administration, user, access, delegate

Can someone please point me to documentation that deals with the situation where **"Bob" is out of the office** for hours/days/weeks, and "Jerry" needs to access "Bob's" SF User to do "Bob's" job?

I thought this was **Delegation**, but I'm finding nothing helpful.  Ifound an Idea that deals with it in some way, but essentially someone needs to LOG IN as "Bob" and act on behalf of "Bob" as "Bob".

Thanks!

Idea link:  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006n5HAAQ

Comment: Is it more about Jerry having the same access as Bob or that Jerry's edits will come with last modified = Bob? Because that seems like it's two different things that could take you down different paths. Delegated users have the ability to manage users meaning they can reset passwords, edit the users and such so it's not substituting Jerry for Bob.

Comment: The ideal scenario is that Jerry is listed as the person doing any edits, but also that it shows he's doing it "on behalf of" Bob.   Second would be the same WITHOUT the on behalf of.  Third would be that "Bob" is doing the edits 9s if Jerry logged on AS BOB).   Those are IDEAL scenarios...

Answer (score 1):

The second scenario is the easiest one to do just ensure that Jerry has the same access be that he's in the same role or above Bob in the role hierarchy. That's how I would tackle this.

The first scenario is slightly harder because there's not really a way to add 'On behalf of' to the last modified by. I suppose you could create a checkbox or picklist to track that data then you can setup a custom setting with code or workflow rules to populate when Jerry is taking over for Bob.

The third scenario is not a best practice. You would not want users to login as other users and changing data. It would be a nightmare to audit and you would never know who did what. By having one license per user you ensure that you can trace back X user changed a field and b record.

Comment: I agree #2 IS the "most logical", it's just not a full solution.  We have "DIVISIONS" at the company (also called Projects, long boring Rootstock limitation reasons).   So when it's a CORPORATE person, not a big deal.  But when it's someone in a specific Division/Project, possible as long as the "delegate" is IN that division (which as I type this, isn't THAT far fetched)..... ugh.       I may be stuck with that (though altering someone's ROle could also affect them doing THEIR OWN job).   I guess *I'm ultimately looking for "LoginAs v2.0" (like Workflows v2.0, aka Process Builder)    Thanks.